# Use jQuery easing plugin with a scrolling function

Tags: jquery, animation, plugins, scroll, easing

I looked for this but i found how to use it with ScrollTo. This one is different.

I need to get the jQuery Easing Plugin working with this function:

```
function ira(id){
      $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top}, 700);
}
```

There's not much more to explain... Thanks in advance for the help!

...

Also, I would like to know if it's possible to set a speed instead of a duration for the animation, so that it takes less if I'm close from my target or more if I'm far from it.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery animations only accepts a duration to determine the speed. For the easing, include the easing js in your page and pass in the third argument to the animation function:

```
 $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top}, 700, "easeInOutCirc");
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! I was trying something like that but I forgot the quotation marks, noobie mistake...

Comment: No prob. It happens all the time with everyone. Take a break once in a while. ;)